# chef inspec validation of the nested json file

Tags: json, chef-infra, devops, inspec

I am using chef inspec to validate in the below json file whether annotation is equal to Test.

```
"imdata": [
    {
        "aaaPwdStrengthProfile": {
            "attributes": {
                "annotation": "Test",
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Trying with the below script but getting error

```
describe json('C:/output.json') do
  its(['imdata','aaaPwdStrengthProfile','attributes','annotation']) { should eq 'Test' }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the JSON file you are trying to test, `imdata` is an array `[]`. The nested dictionary `{ .. }` is the first element (0) of that array.

I created the JSON data from your question as `/tmp/sample.json`. So the inspec test should refer to `'imdata', 0,`, like below:

```rb
describe json('/tmp/sample.json') do
  its(['imdata', 0, 'aaaPwdStrengthProfile', 'attributes', 'annotation']) { should eq 'Test' }
end
```